# Find Nameservers with unknown IP-Addresses in DNS

Tags: powershell, dns

[image]

I want to find all Nameservers which appear in the IP-Address as unknown in all DNS-Zones. However I can not find the entry where this would be displayed. I can easily fix it if I click edit and then press resolve and select the IP, however I have a lot of Zones and so it would require me to edit all of them everytime this happens.

How would I use Powershell to find these zones and display the nameservers that did not resolve?

I started a script like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory,DNSServer
$PDCE = Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service PrimaryDC
$DNSZones = Get-DnsServerZone -ComputerName $PDCE
$DCname = "$aDC."
foreach($aZone in $DNSZones)
{
    Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $azone.ZoneName -RRType ns -ComputerName $PDCE 
}
```

However I can't go further from there and I think it might be the wrong approach. 
Can anyone help me find the right way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you *need* to go further? What results are you getting? What are you expecting?

Comment: Well, basically what I am searching for is a List like the one displayed in the picture. One that tells me which nameserver's IP is "unknown" and which not. Then I could go through the list and maybe remove/add the unknown servers to fix the problem.